# EBike can be subclass of Bike

Tags: java, string, types

I have Bike class if I have types of bikes like Mountain, Road, City, an eBike.  How do I put to put these types of Bikes into code?

```
public class Bike {  
    private String type;
    private String height;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question. It is not really clear what you are asking. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the individual bike types would ot have different attributes other than type, I would use enum instead:

```
public enum BikeType {
    MOUNTAIN, ROAD, CITY, E_BIKE;
}
```

And in your class (also, height should probably not be a string):

```
public class Bike {
    private BikeType type;
    private double height;
    private String name;
}
```

Then, if you have all-args costructor declared, you can create an instance like this:

```
Bike bike = new Bike(BikeType.ROAD, 5.3, "my shiny new bike");
```

But, if you really want to use subclasses, declare classes like this:

```
public class Bike {
    // common parameters
}

public class EBike extends Bike {
    // eBike specific parameters
}
```

Comment: The OP was talking about subclasses. Although your approach to this is valid it is not using sub classes.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that - I will add a comment about that to my answer.

Comment: @Jens And who says that subclassing is the right approach here. I know people that have e city bikes, and others have e mountain bikes. Nope, inheritance doesnt really help here ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat I know that inheritance is not really a good for this and I like the proposal by Ondra more. But sometimes what _we_ think is best is not the right answer for the OP. Maybe this is homework and the OP has to solve this problem with inheritance. Who knows. It is never wrong to also propose a better solution, but you should not forget to answer the original question as well.

Comment: The question is been reworded now.

Comment: @cuteeee I see, but I don't see much difference. Do you not find my answer satisfactory? Do you want to use other approach/does this not solve your problem?